# Multi index dataframe calculations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I calculate the average value in a dataframe?

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
                                         value
symbol  name  description  timestamp

  A    Apple   green        170000         24
                            175000         11
  C    Cranberry red        170000         34
                            175000         29
  G    Grapes  purple       170000         44
                            175000         33
  B    Blueberry  purple    170000         116
                            175000         98
etc.

contains 10000+ rows
```

I want to create 2 new columns on my dataframe where the 1st column will be the average name and the 2nd column will be the avg value which is calculated based on selected symbols.

For example:

```
timestamp avgName avgValue
170000      AC       29
175000      AC       20
etc.
```

Comment: I suppose your multiindex is already a groupby dataframe?

Comment: No, I could not figure out how to select specific rows by groupby. I only found examples using the entire column data

Comment: Hi, so the dataframe you show in your post is not the result of a groupby operation?